# @Valid is ignored for null parameter

Tags: validation, rest, dropwizard

I want to get rid of any unnecessary validation logic in my Dropwizard code. Thus, I added `@Valid` annotations to all resource methods:

```java
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addTask(@Valid Task task) {
    taskDAO.addTask(task);
    // ...
}
```

This works as long as `task` itself is not null. In this case, `addTask()` is called with the invalid value null. I already tried `@Valid @NotNull` in order to further restrict the parameter, nothing changed.

Do I have to check for this error case manually?